# How to set the origin of a volumetric spot knowing its coordinates origin?

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

A 3D spot is defined by a function, close to a 3D densitometric gaussian http://bit.ly/1KjfTYN. Five parametres are necessary: the "brightness", the spreading and three parameters `x0, y0, z0` defining the origin of the spot. x,y and z belong to the interval [-50;50].

The function yields a 3D numpy array containing the densitometric values defining the spot. The shape of such array is (200,200,200).

A 3D spot projected on a plane looks like the left image. The image on the right shows the centre of the spots found from the 3D spot:

[image]

Since the parametres x0,y0,z0 are known,for example:

```
-6.27467613177
-14.0836144387
-15.7856389635
```

It should be possible to write a function with x0, y0, z0 as argument yielding a 3D numpy array equal to 0 everywhere excepted at the origin of the spot where the voxel value should be equal to 1. The following function was supposed to set up the origin of a 3D spot knowing the coordinate origin:

```
def make_spot_origin_3d(x0,y0,z0):
    '''generate a volume V(x0,y0,z0)=1 and equal to 0 elsewhere.
        DOESN'T WORK !!
    '''
    # Create x and y indices
    x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    y = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    z = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)

    X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z,)
    presence = 0*(X <> x0)*(Y <> y0)*(Z <> z0)
    presence = 1*(X == x0)*(Y == y0)*(Z == z0)


    return presence
```

That doesn't work.

So I tried to label the origin from the spot by extracting the coordinates of the origin of a spot:

```
def find_coordinates_spot_origin(volume_array):
    loc_density_max = np.where(volume_array == volume_array.max())
    origin = np.uint16(np.mean(loc_density_max, axis=1))
    return origin
```

Then its possible to set a volume where 1 value(s) label the origin

```
def find_spot_centre(volume_array):
    coord = find_coordinates_spot_origin(volume_array)
    origin_3d = np.zeros(volume_array.shape)
    origin_3d[coord[0],coord[1], coord[2]]=1
    return np.uint16(origin_3d)
```

but its tedious. For example the coordinates of the origin of the spot extracted from the spot, that is from a 3D numpy array, are:

```
(array([71]), array([87]), array([68]))
```

So,I am looking for a function taking a tuple of float,x0, y0,z0 and yielding a 3D array with one voxel equal to 1 at the origin of the spot and filled with zero everywhere.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Here are some things I don't understand, which might help improve the question: What is a spot? Is it a set of 3d points? Are x0, y0 and z0 arrays? Floats? Integers? Are they the coordinates of a voxel? How do they relate to `volume_array`? Can you add an example of the input and the output you hope to generate?

Comment: I hope the question is improved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to create a zero array, and then find the indices of the single point and set that point to `1`.  To find the (x,y,z) indices, you can either use `searchsorted` or do the math yourself.

```
import numpy as np

def make_spot_origin_3d(x0,y0,z0):
    d = np.linspace(-50, 50, 200)
    r = np.zeros(d.shape*3)

    ix = np.searchsorted(d, (x0, y0, z0))
    r[tuple(ix)] = 1

    return r

r = make_spot_origin_3d(45.7, -7.1, 2.9)
```

To verify this:

```
print np.unravel_index(np.argmax(r), r.shape)
#  (191, 86, 106)  # seems reasonable
```

You can also calculate the indices directly.  Here you could replace the line that gives `ix` in the function with:

```
mn, mx, span = -50., 50., 200.
ix = ((np.array([x0, y0, z0])-mn)*span/(mx-mn)).astype(np.int)

print ix
#  [191  85 105]    # similar to above.. but a bit different due to rounding/indexing issues which I don't want to think through right now..
```

Here I'm assuming the same values (ie, -50, 50, 200) are used to descritize each axis just to make this short and simple, but for different values, just write out each axis explicitly.